# how to undecorate all windows xfce

Tags: xfce, devilspie

How can I undecorate all windows in XFCE? I know devilspie2 can do this, but I only know how to do this for specific windows? How should `.ds` script look like to undecorate all? Or do you know any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Consider using `maximus` as suggested here: http://superuser.com/questions/365663/how-do-i-remove-the-title-bar-in-xubuntu

Comment: I've seen this. It's not available in my centos7 repos (forgot to mention distro). Also it seems like all (except blacklisted) would be also maximised. I want to just undecorate. Thank you for try.

Comment: for devilspie2 all that is needed:
cat ~/.config/devilspie2/all.lua 
undecorate_window()

Answer (score 1):

I am using regular devilspie to do this in Cinnamon, not XFCE, but my understanding is that it does this the same way across WMs that support the same protocol, so this should work for you too. I just have a `~/.devilspie/undec.ds` file with only `(undecorate)` in it. It undecorates everything.